# Old tab stops sending requests to API React

Tags: reactjs, axios, use-effect, browser-tab

I have a problem that is hard to describe. The problem is reproduced in 2 cases.

1. Old browser tab (not closed from yesterday's session).
2. After the token is expired, I redirect to the login page, and if I click back in the browser, the problem appears.

## What is the problem?

On such a tab, requests are no longer sent, but the content is drawn from the old data. I don't cache data anywhere.

The query logic is simple. For requests i used axios.

`const getSomeData = async () => { const res = await axios.get('/url')}`

`useEffect(() => getSomeData(), [])`

On such a tab, useEffect does not run. Reloading the page doesn't help. hard reboot too.

In the network tab, I see my request, but it is not marked as Fetсh / XHR and the very first one is loaded, before the scripts are loaded

[sceen all request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBoHQ.png)
[headers request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOmo1.png)

Also in this request, it goes to the localhost and not to the domain, and the token is not sent.

In preview i get the following:

[preview request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7yOf.png)

I think that javascript works because the logic of pressing buttons, opening modal windows works, but requests are not sent on such a tab. But due to the fact that requests are not sent, it does not work, I cannot try to process such a tab

I tried to search this error, but I did not find anything that would help my problem. I also failed to process through useEffect.

Comment: Do you want to send a request when user back to that tab?

Comment: Requests in principle should work on such a tab, if the user comes back to this tab, he will not see new content because requests are not sent

Comment: If you send request in `useEffect` the request won't be sent again when user revisit a tab. because the state stays the same.

Comment: code in useEffect does not work on this tab. it doesn't start. neither on update, nor on state change if I follow deps

Comment: in which browser?

Comment: I think in any. I used Chrome

Comment: I don't know it's a good idea or not, but I think you can run a function with event listeners even in old tabs. maybe on focus or something else. give it a try.